# Python Adjacency -- the range() function

Tags: python, range

I am using a grid system to determine an object's adjacency to another. I'm checking the relative position of the static object to the position of the movable object.

The thing I need help with is the range() function. I need to iterate over (-1, 0, 1) per dimension, so I use

```
range(-1, 1)
```

Which produces -1's and 0's.

Similarly,

```
range(-1, 2)
```

produces the same thing.

I thought arg1 was Start, arg2 was Stop, and optional arg3 was Step defaulted to 1. What gives?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: >>> for x in range(-1, 2): print(x) #output -1 0 1

Comment: That's exactly the same code I have (my code is in Eclipse, not the term). I don't think that would make a difference...

Comment: A range, like a slice, is the first number you want, followed by the first number you *don't* want. You're telling Python you don't want 1, so it is dutifully not giving it to you.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I was returning from the function (inside the second for: loop before it could iterate over the "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ... can't reproduce your troubles:

```
>>> range(-1,1)
[-1, 0]
>>> range(-1, 2)
[-1, 0, 1]
```

Working as expected.